Misbehavior of generic during inheritance
I was trying to simplify the creation of Service layers by allowing the declaration of repository_cls instead of writing an __init__ method every time. However, there are some generic behaviors that are confusing me. I use Pyright for type checking.
class BaseService[T: BaseRepository]:
    repository_cls: Type[T]
    repository: T

    def __init__(self, db: SessionDepends):
        self.db = db
        self.repository = getattr(type(self), "repository_cls")(db)


class SomeService(BaseService):
    repository_cls = SomeRepository
    
    def create_something():
        self.repository # <-- 'unknown' but I expected 'SomeRepository'

I tried changing the repository type to something else to observe its behavior, but in that case, Pyright was able to understand the type.
class BaseService[T: BaseRepository]:
    repository_cls: Type[T]
    repository: str # <-- change to not generic
    ...


class SomeService(BaseService):
    repository_cls = SomeRepository
    
    def create_something():
        self.repository # <-- 'str' exactly that I expected

How can I fix this, or how can I implement it in another way?

Should be class SomeService(BaseService[SomeRepository]): ... - omitted generic params do not mean "please infer me", fortunately, but just default to Any. You're defining class SomeService(BaseService[Any]) from the typechecker's POV. s/Any/Unknown above to match pyright terminology, but that makes almost no difference here.
